# What is the default font value for a dash figure?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm creating an app and I want to reset the figure to the default parameters but I can't find the default font size.
Does anyone know where all the default parameters can be checked?
Or is font automatically set depending on the figure features?

When I print the figure dictionary the field size in font does not exist when I first create it without modifying the size.

Thanks!

Comment: You can find the default values of all parameters in the Plotly Python Figure Reference: https://plotly.com/python/reference/index/.

The default font size is 12: https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-font-size.

Answer (score 0):

For introspecting plotly figures beyond what you get when looking at the basic fig dictionary you could use `fig.full_figure_for_development()`. To get the font size try:

```
fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False).layout.font.size
```